# no such table error when i am creating 2 tables in sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-intent

whenever i am trying to execute the second table which is DATABASE_TABLE1 it is showing no such table error

it is not showing error when i am inserting in the first table but it showing in the second table

```
package com.example.billpay;

import android.content.ContentValues; 
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Process {

public static final String KEY_FNAME="person_fname";
public static final String KEY_LNAME="person_lname";
public static final String KEY_EMAIL="person_email";
public static final String KEY_PHNO="person_pno";
public static final String KEY_UNAME="person_uname";
public static final String KEY_PASS="person_pass";
public static final String KEY_EID="person_electricityid";

public static final String KEY_EBID="person_eid";
public static final String KEY_EMONTH="bill_month";
public static final String KEY_EBREAD="bill_reading";
public static final String KEY_EBAMOUNT="bill_amount";



private static final String DATABASE_NAME="bill";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE="electric";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE1="electricbill";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
        KEY_UNAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_FNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_LNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PHNO + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PASS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                " FOREIGN KEY ("+KEY_EID+") REFERENCES "+DATABASE_TABLE1+" ("+KEY_EBID+"));"
                );

//creation of second table

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE1 + " (" +
        KEY_EBID + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                KEY_EMONTH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EBREAD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EBAMOUNT + " TEXT NOT NULL); "
                );



    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE1);
        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public Process(Context c){
    ourContext=c;

}

public Process open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;

}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();

}

public long createEntry(String pfname, String plname, String pemail,
        String puname, String ppass, String pphno, String peid ) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_FNAME, pfname);
    cv.put(KEY_LNAME, plname);
    cv.put(KEY_EMAIL, pemail);
    cv.put(KEY_UNAME, puname);
    cv.put(KEY_PASS, ppass);
    cv.put(KEY_PHNO, pphno);
    cv.put(KEY_EID, peid);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);    
}


public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_UNAME, KEY_PASS, KEY_PHNO, KEY_EID };
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null , null , null , null , null);
    String result = "";

    int gfname=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_FNAME);
    int glname=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LNAME);
    int gemail=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMAIL);
    int guname=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_UNAME);
    int gpass=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PASS);
    int gphno=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PHNO);
    int geid=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EID);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
        result= result + c.getString(gfname) + " "  + c.getString(glname) + " " + c.getString(gemail) + " "
                + c.getString(guname) + " " + c.getString(gpass) + " "  + c.getString(gphno)  + c.getString(geid) +  "\n";

    }

    return result;

}

public String getpass(String k) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_FNAME, KEY_LNAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_UNAME, KEY_PASS, KEY_PHNO};
    Cursor c=ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_UNAME + "='" + k + "'", null, null, null, null);
    if (c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String rpassword = c.getString(4);
        return rpassword;
    }

    return null;
}


//second DATABASE function
public long createeentry(String peid, String pemonth, String peamount,
        String pereading) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues ph = new ContentValues();
    ph.put( KEY_EBID, peid);
    ph.put( KEY_EMONTH, pemonth);
    ph.put( KEY_EBREAD, pereading);
    ph.put( KEY_EBAMOUNT, peamount);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE1, null, ph);
}

public String getedata() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String col[]= new String[] { KEY_EBID, KEY_EMONTH, KEY_EBREAD, KEY_EBAMOUNT };
    Cursor l= ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE1, col, null, null, null, null, null);
    String eresult="";
    int peid=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBID);
    int pemonth=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMONTH);
    int peread=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBREAD);
    int pamount=l.getColumnIndex(KEY_EBAMOUNT);

    for (l.moveToFirst(); !l.isAfterLast(); l.moveToNext()){
        eresult= eresult + l.getString(peid) + " "  + l.getString(pemonth) + " " + l.getString(peread) + " "
                + l.getString(pamount) +  "\n";

    }
    return eresult;
}}
```

i am also using a foreign key atrribute.Hope that i am using it coreect
here is the error which is coming up

```
04-24 14:31:37.864: E/SQLiteLog(16297): (1) no such table: electricbill
04-24 14:32:09.080: D/AndroidRuntime(16438): Shutting down VM
04-24 14:32:09.081: W/dalvikvm(16438): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught     exception (group=0x40e06908)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [When is SQLiteOpenHelper onCreate() / onUpgrade() run?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run) - uninstall your app and try again

Answer (score 0):

Try running again, this time after incrementing the Database Version. You probably tested this out previously with just the first table, triggering the creation. But succeeding launches won't try to call the onUpgrade (which will call onCreate after dropping the tables) unless the database version has changed.

An alternative is to uninstall the previous build from your emulator/phone then install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Change version of your database or uninstall your app and then install again it will definitely work